# Swift PreviewProvider failing to initalize view variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data

I am using CoreData in a SwiftUI project with a relationship as follows:

```
Climb:
- timestamp: Date
- grade: Int16
- attempts: Int16
...

Session:
- timestamp: Date
- climbs: [Climb] # A list of Climb objects
```

My first view is displaying all of the past sessions, and when you click on one session I want it to go to a different view to show all the climbs within that session. My issue is that I can not reference the `climbs` variable properly in the new view when using `PreviewProvider`.

Based on other StackOverflow questions, and [this](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/one-to-many-relationships-with-core-data-swiftui-and-fetchrequest) document, I added

```
extension Session {
    public var climbArray: [Climb] {
        let set = climbs as? Set<Climb> ?? []
        return set.sorted {
            $0.timestamp! < $1.timestamp!
        }
    }
}
```

to my Session object, but when trying to reference `climbArray` in the view, the size is always zero. Here is an MVP example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SessionDetailView: View {
    var session: Session
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Length \(session.climbArray.count)")
        }
    }
}

struct SessionDetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SessionDetailView(session: {
            let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
            let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
            
            let climbOne: Climb = Climb(context: viewContext)
            climbOne.grade = 2
            climbOne.attempts = 1
            climbOne.sent = true
            climbOne.timestamp = Date()
            
            let climbTwo: Climb = Climb(context: viewContext)
            climbTwo.grade = 5
            climbTwo.attempts = 4
            climbTwo.sent = true
            climbTwo.timestamp = Date()
            
            let session: Session = Session(context: viewContext)
            session.climbs = [climbOne, climbTwo]
            
            return session
        }())
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}
```

No matter what I try, `Text("Length \(session.climbArray.count)")` always ends up displaying `Length 0` and so a list of the climbs is never generated.

I am very new to Swift and this is my first project, so I apologize if the answer is obvious. I would appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
```

To

```
let result = PersistenceController.preview
```

Also, you should have something like

```
session.addToClimbs(climbOne)
```

And change

```
var session: Session
```

To

```
@ObservedObject var session: Session
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the `PersistenceController(inMemory: true)` which should have been `let result = PersistenceController.preview`! Also, as a quick correction if anyone sees this in the future, it's `session.addToClimbs(climbOne)` not `session.climbs.addToClimbs(climbOne)`. But everything else worked! Thanks!